# Submit form on button click and disable button

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony

Please I need your help, I want to disable a button on click and submit my form this is the code

```
            {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'myForm'}}) }}

                    //....... NOT important

                {{ form_rest(form) }}

                <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light fullwidth" type="submit" id="monBttn"  onclick="myFunction()" name="action"
                        value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}">
                    <i class="material-icons left">save</i>
                    Enregistrer
                </button>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
```

In my button i called a fuction this is the code

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        buttn = document.getElementById("monBttn");
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        buttn.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
</script>
```

my script does not work the button is disabled but it does'nt submit the value
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can use selector.attr('disabled','disabled'); property to disable button.

Comment: what is the output of `document.getElementById("myForm")` ? is the id correctly set on the `form` element ? any error shown ?

Comment: that only works with jquery @WisdmLabs

Comment: document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true; this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create one demo. It is working fine.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
            this.disabled = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: the question is not tagged as jquery!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById("monBttn").disabled = true;
```

and you can also display the "please wait" message.

```
document.getElementById("monBttn").disabled = "Please wait..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx guys for the help this is the working script:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("monBttn").disabled = true; 
        document.getElementById("monBttn").innerHTML = "Traitement en cours...";
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```